# How to use NServiceBus in your own process?

Tags: nservicebus

I am trying to use NServiceBus in my own console applications. I've followed the documentation found at http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/

This leaves me with a project that will not build because of error "The type or namespace name 'NServiceBus' could not be found".

The types are found however and are fully browsable and have functioning intellisense.

What piece is missing from the NServiceBus documentation to allow the sample to compile ?

(I can post code, but the point is that the documentation page was followed but might be incomplete.)

Comment: Did you unblock the NSB dlls after downloading?

Comment: yes. Thought that might be it anyway and checked again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed:
I've seen this issue in other posts, but had not connected it to the missing reference error I've been getting.

NServiceBus requires the Full .Net profile, not the Client Profile.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Using NServiceBus in your own console application should be relatively straight forward. Check out some of the samples in the download for how to do this. Here is an example from the sendonly sample:

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var bus = Configure.With()
            .UnityBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .UnicastBus()
            .SendOnly();

        bus.Send("SendOnlyDestination@someserver",new TestMessage());

        Console.WriteLine("Message sent to remote endpoint, you can verify this by looking at the outgoing queues in you msmq MMC-snapin"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only one I know with code sample in own process is the Async. I've opened that solution, built etc. Then added a console app, referenced the same 3 DLL's that Async was and get same error.